With $X$ and $Y$ being two independent $\text{Bernoulli(1/3)}$ rvs, show whether $U = |Y-X|,~V = X+Y$ are independent or not

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent $\text{Bernoulli(1/3)}$ random variables. Define random variables $U$ and $V$ as $$U = |Y-X|, \hspace{5mm} V = X+Y$$ Are $U$ and $V$ independent?

I am new to the field of Statistics and very excited to work on this site.
One way is, I calculate the joint PMF table of $U$ and $V$ and Marginal PMF using joint PMF and check for each value in table. But since the question just asked for "Are $U$ and $V$ independent or not?", Is there any short way of answering the question?
Table looks something like this which shows that $U$ and $V$ aren't independent
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \frac{V}{U} & 0 & 1 & 2 & f_U(u)\\
    \hline
    0 & 4/9 & 0 & 1/9 & 5/9\\
    \hline
    1 & 0 & 4/9 & 0 & 4/9\\
    \hline
    f_V(v) & 4/9 & 4/9 & 1/9 & 1\\
    \hline
\end{array}

You don't need the entire table, once you check that $P(U=0,V=0)\ne P(U=0)P(V=0)$.

Your method is a good way of showing lack of independence and will work in many other examples.
Another way in this particular example, which would work in some other cases when $X$ and $Y$ are integers, is to see that $U=|Y-X|$ and $V=X+Y$ are integers which can each be even or odd.  But $U$ and $V$ must have the same parity as each other, and so are not independent.

I didn’t get what you are trying to say

He says that if $U$ is odd, then $V$ is odd (same if you replace odd with even). So knowing somethingh about $U$ tells you something about $V$. That is dependence!

@kjetilbhalvorsen Ah... OK, Thanks!
